# Is it Possible to Disable the Triggers in the SQL Server 2012 for the Particular Stored Procedure Run While it will be active in the other Processes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Is it possible to disable the triggers for a particular stored procedure run while it will be active in the other processes?

Like if

```
update Table A 
having Update Trigger TrA with a SP
```

Trigger will not work but if I do the update manually will the trigger work?
Any property for the SP.

Comment: Triggers are product specific. Please [edit] your question to add a tag identifying your product.

Comment: if it is for sql server,you could start with something like ,knowing proc name and rolling back:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467961/how-to-get-the-stored-procedure-name-from-a-trigger-when-an-update-operation-was

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Triggers are actually defined by the ISO/ANSI SQL standard. (But most products have their own versions.)

Comment: Updated,Please Suggest for the SQL Server

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks can u please elavorate?